# Keyboard not working while entering root password(Linux)

Tags: keyboard, root, sudo, parrot-os

I'm using Parrot security OS MATE. The keyboard working fine elsewhere but when I try to enter my root password for using any elevated privileges, the keyboard stops working.

Comment: You can ask this question in https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't know that Linux terminal Hide password type feedback.
Just type your password correctly and hit enter. It you will works. If you enter wrong password then It will show you

```
Sorry, try again.
```

If you want to see your keystroke feedback in terminal then open your terminal `Ctrl + Alt + T` and Run

```
sudo visudo
```

And enter your password **correctly**

[image]

You will see file like one below. Using arrow keys, navigate to the end of line:

```
Defaults env_reset
```

[image]

Add this line with `,pwfeedback` . Result should look like this:

```
Defaults env_reset,pwfeedback
```

[image]

Save with `Ctrl + X` and then typing `y` and hit “Enter” to accept
Now close and re-launch command prompt to see if this worked or not.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It will not show the password while typing the password. So it's not your keyboard error. It's yoir error. I think u need to start from ubuntu